# Sum each row in a CSV file and sort it by specific value bash

Tags: linux, bash, row

i have a question taking the below set Coma separated CSV i want to run a script in bash that sums all values from colums 7,8,9 from an especific city and show the row with the max value
so Original dataset:

```
Row,name,city,age,height,weight,good rates,bad rates,medium rates
1,john,New York,25,186,98,10,5,11
2,mike,New York,21,175,87,19,6,21
3,Sandy,Boston,38,185,88,0,5,6
4,Sam,Chicago,34,167,76,7,0,2
5,Andy,Boston,31,177,85,19,0,1
6,Karl,New York,33,189,98,9,2,1
7,Steve,Chicago,45,176,88,10,3,0

the desire output will be

Row,name,city,age,height,weight,good rates,bad rates,medium rates,max rates by city
2,mike,New York,21,175,87,19,6,21,46
5,Andy,Boston,31,177,85,19,0,1,20
7,Steve,Chicago,45,176,88,10,3,0,13
```

im trying with this; but it gives me only the highest rate number so 46 but i need it by city and that shows all the row, any ideas how to continue?

`awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","}{sum = 0; for (i=7; i<=9;i++) sum += $i} NR ==1 || sum >max {max = sum}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this awk:

```sh
awk '
BEGIN {FS=OFS=","}
NR==1 {
   print $0, "max rates by city"
   next
}
{
   s = $7+$8+$9
   if (s > max[$3]) {
      max[$3] = s
      rec[$3] = $0
   }
}
END {
   for (i in max)
      print rec[i], max[i]
}' file

Row,name,city,age,height,weight,good rates,bad rates,medium rates,max rates by city
7,Steve,Chicago,45,176,88,10,3,0,13
2,mike,New York,21,175,87,19,6,21,46
5,Andy,Boston,31,177,85,19,0,1,20
```

or to get tabular output:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} NR==1{print $0, "max rates by city"; next} {s=$7+$8+$9; if (s > max[$3]) {max[$3] = s; rec[$3] = $0}} END {for (i in max) print rec[i], max[i]}' file | column -s, -t

Row  name   city      age  height  weight  good rates  bad rates  medium rates  max rates by city
7    Steve  Chicago   45   176     88      10          3          0             13
2    mike   New York  21   175     87      19          6          21            46
5    Andy   Boston    31   177     85      19          0          1             20
```